# Carregar versão web de um site e não a versão mobile em um WebView

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-webview

Como carregar no `WebView` do Xamarin.Android um site completo? Ele está trazendo a versão mobile.

Exemplo:

Estou falando pro `WebView` ir para

https://www.meusite.com.br

E está trazendo:

https://m.meusite.com.br

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688030/setting-webview-to-view-desktop-site-and-not-mobile-site/14688100

Comment: Dei ja uma olhada porem preciso uma solução par XAMARIN.

Comment: Independente da resposta que postei der certo, é legal sempre você postar como está seu código. Assim facilita vermos como está sua estrutura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema você deve alterar o User-Agent(UA) da WebView. Lendo a [documentação](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Webkit.WebSettings.UserAgentString/) da WebView do Xamarin, por padrão, se nada for informado ele irá criar baseado na versão do dispositivo. Como criará um UA baseado em uma versão de celular, o site reconhece e redireciona para versão mobile. Se você sobrescrever o UA e dizer que você está "usando" um computador, o site não irá redirecionar.

Um exemplo de código para alterar o UA:

```
public class SurveyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
            {
                view.Settings.UserAgentString = "ua-string";
                view.LoadUrl(url);


                return true;
            }
        }
```

Onde está o UA-String você pode usar esse do Google Chrome no Windows 7:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
```

Caso queira outro UA, podes consultar nessa [lista](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings).

Comment: Lucas, ele está usando Xamarin. Isso seria no Android Java !?

Answer (score 0):

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(DesktopWebViewRenderer))]

public class DesktopWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    }
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014743/xamarin-webview-request-desktop-site)